# Creating tabitem in wpf C# xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

Is it possible to position the tapitem like this:

[image]

Child (Content) should span over grid but the parent (TapItem) shouldnt do this.

I tried it as following.

```
 <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" x:Name="PropertyBarWidth"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" x:Name="DrawingAreaWidth"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" x:Name="LibraryWidth"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" x:Name="OpenDrawings" Background="{StaticResource B_drawingarea}" BorderThickness="0">
            <TabItem Header="Test" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}">
                <local:UserControl1></local:UserControl1>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

        <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="2" Fill="{StaticResource B_propertybar}"/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="100" Width="20"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{StaticResource B_propertybar}"/>

</Grid>
```

The problem here is, that the `gridsplitter` shouldn't move the content of the `tabitem`. But the left and right areas should move with the `tapitem` itself.

Maybe someone can help, thanks!

Comment: It's still not clear what you are trying to achieve, are there two grid splitters per tab, or one is common for all tabs?

Comment: I've a drawingarea, the usercontrol, in the tabitem. And left and right I ve a propertybars for the drawing objects. When I use the gridsplitters to change the width of the propertybars, the drawingarea should not move with (the view of the drawingarea should be separately changeable with scrollviewer and zooming). On the other side the headers of the tabitems should be between the propertybars.

Comment: one (or two) GridSplitters for all tabs^^

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve looks more feasible with a Docking control than with a simple Grid splitter, just use the [Xceed AvalonDock](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.html) control, don't waste your time reinventing the wheel ;}:

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:xcad="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1024">
<Grid>
    <xcad:DockingManager BorderThickness="1">
        <xcad:LayoutRoot x:Name="LayoutRoot">
            <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane IsMaximized="True" >
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorable ContentId="MainTab" Title="MainTab" CanHide="False" CanClose="False"
                              AutoHideWidth="240">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border Background="LightSalmon"/>
                            <!--your main panel with the drawing usercontrol-->
                        </Grid>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
            </xcad:LayoutPanel>

            <xcad:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>
                <xcad:LayoutAnchorSide>
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="LeftSideTools" ContentId="LeftSide">
                            <Grid>
                                <Border Background="LightSalmon"/>
                                <!--your left panel tools--> 
                            </Grid>
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                </xcad:LayoutAnchorSide>
            </xcad:LayoutRoot.LeftSide> 
            <xcad:LayoutRoot.RightSide>
                <xcad:LayoutAnchorSide>
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="RightSideTools" ContentId="RightSide">
                            <Grid>
                                <Border Background="LightSalmon"/>
                                <!--your right panel tools--> 
                            </Grid>
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                </xcad:LayoutAnchorSide>
            </xcad:LayoutRoot.RightSide>
        </xcad:LayoutRoot>
    </xcad:DockingManager>
</Grid>
```

[Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xceed.Products.Wpf.Toolkit.AvalonDock/) is the package nugget.

Comment: Looks not bad, thanks! Is it free for a commercial use? In the nuget Gallery I only see "
You can try this package for free for 45 days, after which you will need to purchase a license key to continue using it." but I cant find any buy possibility.

Comment: @user10419906 as far as i know the Extended WPF Toolkit (which AvalonDock is part of) is free and opensource (usable in a commercial product as well): https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit

The plus version is not: https://xceed.com/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/